# What does "error code=H10" mean and how do I fix it

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to deploy my app into heroku but each time I do it, I keep getting an application error. When I went to check out the logs, these series of errors showed up.

```
2021-04-15T15:47:19.211428+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ammans-signin-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=e4f2e604-6a98-4ee4-b1db-e1336ff367aa fwd="71.68.52.24" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-04-15T15:47:20.496362+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-04-15T15:47:22.396211+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ammans-signin-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=6ef5768a-f573-4cee-a28f-06c2d8e99b73 fwd="71.68.52.24" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-04-15T15:47:22.546475+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ammans-signin-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=dcb1e825-1051-4043-aff8-4661f9d99f7c fwd="71.68.52.24" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-04-15T15:47:23.408822+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ammans-signin-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=377fbf8b-3693-407b-9bb3-cbb5126dd4bc fwd="71.68.52.24" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-04-15T15:47:23.568012+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ammans-signin-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=78b4967c-c13a-433d-8824-9b8056d96db5 fwd="71.68.52.24" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-04-15T15:47:24.345343+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ammans-signin-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=ba910d05-63ea-49a1-afa3-898ca66a7be9 fwd="71.68.52.24" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-04-15T15:47:24.483755+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ammans-signin-backend.herokuapp.com request_id=7266bb9b-f90f-4181-a64e-f07ada567bb8 fwd="71.68.52.24" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

What do these errors mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: This is the problem with `Procfile` maybe.. Share your `Procfile` then anyone can help.

Comment: https://github.com/AmmanMeb/Forum/blob/main/server/Procfile

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, My Procfile was in the wrong folder. It was in the client folder instead of the server. moving it removed the error